# I already use if (isset($_POST['sub'])) in my code. But it show Undefined index: category

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I already use `if(isset($_POST['sub']))` in my code. But it show Notice: Undefined index: category in C:\xampp\htdocs\online shop\controlar\product.php on line 100. This is a simple product upload page. When I try to upload a product it works fine but doesn't work in the category, I mean category not add in the database.
[image]
**product.php**

```
<?php
require_once("/../dataAccessLayer/dalSession.php");
session::checkA();
require_once("/../dataAccessLayer/dalProduct.php");
require_once("/../dataAccessLayer/dalSub-Category.php");
require_once("/../dataAccessLayer/dalCategory.php");
require_once("/../dataAccessLayer/dalSize.php");
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <title>Add Product</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src='../js/jquery.scrollto.js'></script>
</head>

  <body>
 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action']== "logout")){
   Session::StopA();
  }
  ?>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Add Product
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">            

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../index.php" target="_blank">Visit Site</a>     </li>
            <li><a href="?action=logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
   <div class="container-fluid main-container">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li> <a href="admin.php">Home</a></li>

    <li ><a href="category.php">Category Details</a></li>

    <li><a href="../controlar/sub-category.php">Sub-Category Details</a></li>

    <li><a href="../controlar/size.php">Size Details</a></li>

    <li class="active"><a href="../controlar/product.php">Product Details</a></li>

    <li><a href="../controlar/service.php">Delivery Charge Details</a></li>

    <li><a href="report.php">Sell Report</a></li>

    <li><a href="delivary_view.php">Order View</a></li>

    <li><a href="member_view.php">Member List</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 content">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 align="center"><b><u>Add New Product</u></b></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
    <h3><a href="product_view.php">View Product</a></h3>
   <?php

   if (isset($_POST['sub'])){

   $pro = new Product();
   $pro->p_name = $_POST['name'];
  $pro->price = $_POST['price'];
  $pro->vat = $_POST['vat'];
 $pro->discount = $_POST['discount'];
  $pro->picture = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
 $pro->details = $_POST['details'];
 $pro->quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
 $pro->subcat_id = $_POST['subcatagory'];
  $pro->cat_id = $_POST['category']; //100 line
 $pro->size_id = $_POST['size'];

if ($pro->Insert()) {
   echo "Insert Sucessfully";

   $image_type = $_FILES['pic']['type'];
   if ($image_type=='image/jpeg' || $image_type=='image/jpg' ||   $image_type=='image/png') 
   {

          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'],'../image/'.$_FILES['pic']['name']);
    }

 }
 else { 
      echo "Data Failed";
      //echo $_POST['size'];
 }


 }

 ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Vat:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vat" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Discount:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="discount" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Picture:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="pic" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Details:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="details" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub-Category:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="subcatagory" id="siz">
                <?php
                 $ser = new SubCategory();
                 $load = $ser->Load();
                 echo $load;    
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Category:</td>
        <td><div id="cos" name="category"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Size:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="size">
                <?php
                    $size = new Size();
                    $size->View_dd();
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>   

  </table>
 </form>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
<hr>
  </body>
 </html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#siz").change(function(){
  var ser_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"show_category_delivery.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{ser_Id:ser_id},
    dataType:"HTML",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $("#cos").html(data);
    }
  });

    });
   });
   </script>
```

**dalProduct.php**

```
<?php

class Product {

public $product_id;
public $p_name;
public $price;
public $vat;
public $discount;
public $picture;
public $details;
public $quantity;
public $subcat_id;
public $cat_id;
public $size_id;    

public function DB()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");
    return $connection;
}

public function SelectById()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT product.product_id, product.p_name, product.price, product.vat, product.discount, product.picture, product.details, product.quantity, subcategory.name, size.size_name 
                FROM product,subcategory,size 
                WHERE product.subcategory_id = subcategory.subcategory_id 
                AND product.size_id = size.size_id 
                AND product.product_id = '".$this->product_id."'";
        $sql = mysqli_query($this->DB(),$sql);
        while($d = mysqli_fetch_row($sql))
        {
            return $d;
        }
    }

public function Insert()
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product (p_name, price, vat, discount, picture,  details, quantity, subcategory_id, category_id, size_id) 
           VALUES ('".$this->p_name."', 
                    '".$this->price."', 
                    '".$this->vat."', 
                    '".$this->discount."', 
                    '".$this->picture."', 
                    '".$this->details."', 
                    '".$this->quantity."', 
                    '".$this->subcat_id."', 
                    '".$this->cat_id."', 
                    '".$this->size_id."');";

    if(mysqli_query($this->DB(), $sql))
    {
            return true;
    }
        return false;
}

public function Update()
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE product SET p_name = '".$this->p_name."',
                                     price = '".$this->price."',  
                                     vat = '".$this->vat."',
                                        discount = '".$this->discount."', 
                                        picture = '".$this->picture."', 
                                        details = '".$this->details."',
                                     quantity = '".$this->quantity."', 
                                     subcategory_id = '".$this->subcat_id."', 
                                     size_id = '".$this->size_id."'
                            WHERE product_id = '".$this->product_id."'";

        if(mysqli_query($this->DB(),$sql))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;   
    }

public function View()
{
    $sql = "SELECT product.product_id, product.p_name, product.price, product.vat,
                product.discount, product.picture, product.details, product.quantity,
                subcategory.name, size.size_name
                FROM product,subcategory,size
                WHERE product.subcategory_id = subcategory.subcategory_id AND
                 product.size_id = size.size_id";
    $sql_connect = mysqli_query($this->DB(),$sql);
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_connect))
        {
            $arr[] = $d;
        }
        return $arr;
}

public function Delete()
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id = '".$this->product_id."'";
        if(mysqli_query($this->DB(),$sql))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Because you don't have `input` with name `category`

Comment: yes you did mistake here `<td><div id="cos" name="category"></div></td>`
insted of input

Comment: category is automatically selected when sub-category is select

Comment: but obviously not as a form element. you could make a hidden input and fill that via js if you don't want to show the category as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you alternative suggestion:
Just add below code and write category id manually.

```
<td>Category:</td>
        <td><div id="cos"></div> <input type="text" id="category" name="category" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: The category is automatically selected when sub-category is select** 
in line number 169 you should use

```
<td><div id="cos" name="divCategory"></div> <input type="hidden" id="category" name="category" /></td>
```

changed name of div to `divCategory`

Comment: did you count the 69 lines from 100 to 169?!

Comment: @Jeff No, I just simply copy the whole code into my editor to determine which line number has a problem.

Comment: @MdRakibulIslam Have you try after changing the name of div?

Comment: What are you getting in the AJAX response? Have you bound the coming category data with the hidden field on the success of AJAX?